# Obtain accounts from all ServiceAccounts OU's across child-domains

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I've been tasked with providing a list of all service accounts across multiple domains, but wither only receive accounts from the primary domain or get an "a referral was returned from the server"

If I run the code below, it returns the service accounts from the primary domain, but not the child domains.  If I edit the code and manually put in one of the child domains, it will return "a referral was returned from the server" error.  I've tried using a global catalog server and port (3268) as the server but still get the "referral" error.  I'm relatively new to PowerShell, so I apologize up front if I've left out any information you much need.

```
$domains = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest() | Select Domains

ForEach($domain in $domains.Domains){
    $ous = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like 'ServiceAccounts'" -Server ($domain.Name) -SearchScope Subtree)    
}

$ous | ForEach-Object{Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName} | Select SamAccountName | Export-Csv c:\temp\service.csv
```

Basically I need to find all OU's named "ServiceAccounts" and export the users of each to a csv file, from both the primary domain and child domains. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently overwriting `$ous` every time the loop runs, and additionally you'll need to pass the appropriate `Server` argument to `Get-ADUser` as well.

Move it inside the `foreach(){}` loop:

```
$domains = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest() | Select Domains

$users = foreach($domain in $domains.Domains){
    $ous = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like 'ServiceAccounts'" -Server $domain.Name -SearchScope Subtree
    foreach($ou in $ous){
        Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou.DistinguishedName -Server $domain.Name |Select SamAccountName,@{Name='Domain';Expression = {$domain.Name}}
    }
}

$users | Export-Csv c:\temp\service.csv
```